# Vuex getters has undefined data when I try to load data from API and use it in multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a page component where I am making api call and storing the data in Vuex store through actions. This data has to be used at multiple places but everywhere I'm initially getting undefined data which loads after a few seconds asynchronously from the API. How should I use vuex getters asynchronously ?

Here's the code for my vuex store module :

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
  all_pokemon: {},
  pokemon_details: {}
};

const getters = {
  getAllPokemon: function(state) {
    return state.all_pokemon;
  },
  getPokemonDetails: function(state) {
    return state.pokemon_details;
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setAllPokemon: function(state, payload) {
    return state.all_pokemon = payload;
  },
  setPokemon: function(state, payload) {
    console.log('Pokemon details set with payload ', payload);
    return state.pokemon_details = payload;
  }
};

const actions = {
  setPokemonAction: function({ commit }, passed_pokemon) {
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + passed_pokemon)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Response data is : ', response.data);
      });
    commit('setAllPokemon', response.data);
  },
  setPokemonDetailAction: function({ commit }, passed_pokemon) {
    console.log('Action method called..', passed_pokemon);
    axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + passed_pokemon)
      .then((response) => {
        commit('setPokemon', response.data);
      });
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
};
```

And code for the component where I want to get this data and pass it to other components :

```
<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
  import axios from 'axios'

  // Imported other components here 

  export default {
    name: 'pokemon_detail_page',
    data() {
      return {
        current_pokemon: this.$route.params.pokemon,
        isLoading: false,
        childDataLoaded: false,
        search_pokemon: '',
        sprites: [],
        childData: 'False',
        isAdded: false,
        pokemon_added: 'none_display',
        show: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'setPokemonDetailAction',
        'removePokemon'
      ]),
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'getPokemonDetails',
        'getTeam'
      ])
    },
    components: {
      Game_index,
      PulseLoader,
      PokemonComponent,
    },
    filters: {

    },
    watch: {
      getTeam: function (val) {
      },
      getPokemonDetails: function(val) {
      }
    },

    created() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.show = true;
      }, 2000);
      this.$store.dispatch('setPokemonDetailAction', this.current_pokemon)
        .then(() => {
            // const { abilities, name, order, species,  } = {...this.getPokemonDetails};

        })
    },
    mounted() {

    },
  }
</script>
```

And here's is the code for the template where I'm passing this data to multiple components :

```
       <div v-if="show" class="pokemon_stats_container" :key="childData">
            <ability-component
                    :abilities="getPokemonDetails.abilities"
            >
            </ability-component>

            <sprites-component
                    :sprites="sprites"
            >
            </sprites-component>

            <location-component
                    :location_area="getPokemonDetails.location_area_encounters"
                    :id="getPokemonDetails.id"
            >
            </location-component>

            <stats-component
                    :stats="getPokemonDetails.stats"
            >
            </stats-component>

            <game_index
                    :game_indices="getPokemonDetails.game_indices"
            />

            <moves-component
                    :moves="getPokemonDetails.moves"
                    :pokemon_name="getPokemonDetails.name"
            >
            </moves-component>

        </div>
```

As of now, I've adopted a roundabout way of doing this through setTimeout and setting a variable after 2 seconds so that data is available for other  components to use. But, there has to be a more elegant way of handling vuex asynchronous data. Someone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first commit is not in the promise

```
 commit('setAllPokemon', response.data);
```

make this :

```
  axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + passed_pokemon)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Response data is : ', response.data);
        commit('setAllPokemon', response.data);
      });
```

try to use in your vue component

```
$forceUpdate()
```

when your request is end for reload the data